# Android using Bluetooth MAP

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-profile

I am going to write an app for 2 android devices using MAP. Currently I am in gathering information stage. As far as I know some of the Android devices support MAP profile just out of the box (so one can connect it to the car).

For some reason unfortunately I cannot see any API to use this profile anyway. Is this possible to somehow use this profile in a simple manner? Or I have to write everything alone from scratch. How can I add to the android bluetooth support for any new profile? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right, the MAP profile on Android phone does not need user's operation i.e. it is out of box, just like other profiles, e.g. A2DP or PBAP.

So I assume you would like implement the MAP client role profile? just like the role on the car, then you may refer the code on android source:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/bluetooth/+/master/src/android/bluetooth/client/map
Yes it is possible to do that.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, thanks. Not sure though why I couldn't find this on android developers site.

Comment: generally the MAP client code was not built into most of the android image(due to different roles), so you could not find them on developers site. enjoy it :-)

Comment: New link https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothMapClient.java